# Unable to combine two different mbtiles

Tags: vector, openmaptiles

I am trying to combine my vector tiles (generated by a shapefile) based on [this](https://openmaptiles.org/docs/generate/custom-vector-from-shapefile-geojson/) tutorial with another mbtile file of a specific country, which I downloaded from openmaptiles.
I host the mbtiles in a local tileserver, which lives in a vagrant machine. And I display them on a mapping client using OL3. I am able to display without any issues the second mbtile (the one with the country) by using the below parameters for defining the source:

```
"data_vector":{
    "type": "vector",
    "tiles": [
      "http://localhost:8080/data/v3/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf"]
  }
```

I want to add another source with the other mbtile file. According to [this](https://openmaptiles.org/docs/raster/custom-raster/) tutorial, I can combine the mbtile files by adding one more source.
I tried that by doing the following:

```
"mymaptiles": {
      "type": "vector",
      "url": "mbtiles:///Users/dkar/workspaces/other/workshops/osmfoundation_workshop/opt/maps/wld_poi_warehouses_wfp.mbtiles"
  }
```

But then when I try to access the map from the browser I get the following error:

```
TileJSON.js:85 Failed to load mbtiles:///Users/dkar/workspaces/other/workshops/osmfoundation_workshop/opt/maps/wld_poi_warehouses_wfp.mbtiles: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

Is this the correct way to make it work? If yes, how do I make the mbtile appear on the map?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, your problem is that you need to make your custom mbtiles at: `///Users/dkar/workspaces/other/workshops/osmfoundation_workshop/opt/maps/wld_poi_warehouses_wfp.mbtiles` available on a webserver. Your browser does not allow you to access your local file storage.